# Automatically load packages at startup

Tags: packages, kernel, initialization

I'm a physics student and I try to simplify my day with *Mathematica*. Every time I use *Mathematica* I need `Div[]`, `Grad[]`, `Curl[]`, etc., so I use `` Needs["VectorAnalysis`"] ``.

My question is: Is there any way to tell *Mathematica* that the package `` VectorAnalysis` `` should always be loaded? It would simplify my day enormously.

By the way, I tried

```
DeclarePackage["VectorAnalysis`", {"Div", "Grad", "Curl"}]
```

from the *Mathematica* tutorial on [Automatic Loading of Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AutomaticLoadingOfPackages.html), which says:

> When you first use Grad, Mathematica automatically loads the package that defines it.

Unfortunately, nothing happens. The functions are still unknown, until I use `` Needs["VectorAnalysis`"] ``

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix my problem?

Comment: Look up `init.m` in the docs.

Answer (score 12):

As J.M. pointed out, this can be achieved by using an `init.m` file.

`init.m` files are loaded on startup. The documentation can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html).

To load the `VectorAnalysis` package on each startup, you can write the init file using `Export`. The snippet below will append a `` Needs["VectorAnalysis`"] `` to the kernel `init.m` file:

```
initFileName = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}];

(* Make a back-up *)
CopyFile[initFileName, initFileName <> "_" <>
   StringReplace[ToString@Round[DateList[]], " " -> ""] <> ".bak"];

exprs = Import[initFileName, {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}];

Export[initFileName,
    Append[exprs, HoldComplete[Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]]],
    {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}
]
```

Comment: Warning. This routine hosed my init.m file, completely emptying it. (Running Mma 7 on Win 7.)

Comment: I´d also opine that modifying important init files by hand would be the safer alternative than scripting (even with backup) in most cases

Comment: THANKS MAN!!!! U MADE MY DAY!! Thats exacly what i want....nice I'm new in this board, but actually now i think one of the most efficient boards...thanks again...maybe u'll hear about me with another question, but i hope next time, i can help :)

Answer (score 4):

On Mathematica 7 (at least) `DeclarePackage` doesn't work first time on this Curl example:

```
DeclarePackage["VectorAnalysis`", {"Div", "Grad", "Curl"}]

v := {3 Xx^2 + 2 Yy + (a  - 3 b)  Zz,
   (b - 7 a) Xx - 5 Yy - Zz,
   2 Xx + c a Yy + 7 Zz}

Curl[v]
```

> {0, 0, 0}

But strangely when `v` is defined again and run it works:

```
v := {3 Xx^2 + 2 Yy + (a  - 3 b)  Zz,
   (b - 7 a) Xx - 5 Yy - Zz,
   2 Xx + c a Yy + 7 Zz}

Curl[v]
```

> {1 + a c, -2 + a - 3 b, -2 - 7 a + b}

On the other hand `Needs` works first time:

```
Quit

Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]

v := {3 Xx^2 + 2 Yy + (a  - 3 b)  Zz,
   (b - 7 a) Xx - 5 Yy - Zz,
   2 Xx + c a Yy + 7 Zz}

Curl[v]
```

> {1 + a c, -2 + a - 3 b, -2 - 7 a + b}

You could manually add `` Needs["VectorAnalysis`"] `` to the init file referred to by Malte, found at `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`.

Comment: `DeclarePackage` fails here because you create a shadowing problem by first using `Xx` etc., before `Curl`.  To fix this you need to include these `DeclarePackage` so that they are created in the correct Context:  ``DeclarePackage["VectorAnalysis`", {"Div", "Grad", "Curl", "Uu", "Vv", 
  "Xx", "Xxi", "Yy", "Zz"}]``

Comment: Quit needs a bracket pair.