# How can I load packages automatically after reopening Mathematica

Tags: packages, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically load packages at startup](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/automatically-load-packages-at-startup)

I have made two packages "Package1" and "Package2". Package2 calls Package1. it works fine.But everytime I am reopening `Mathematica`,I have to run both packages and then load them by `Needs`. I dont want to load packages again and again.

Comment: If Package2 relies on Package1, I'd suggest loading it using the second argument of `BeginPackage` in Package2.  This ensures that you only need to load Package2 manually before using it (and not Package1 as well).

Comment: @Szabolcs What you described is a public import which is only recommended in cases when the functionality of the second package (Package1) needs to be available for the users of Package2. In all other cases, a private import through calling ``Needs["Package1`"]`` in the ``Private` `` section of Package2 is the better method, for the sake of encapsulation and information hiding.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It does not in fact need to be in the ``Private` `` section for the import to be private, as it is the `EndPackage` of Package2 that removed the Package1 context from the context path.

Comment: @Szabolcs What I described is a standard practice (see R.Maeder's PIM for example). Your suggestion will work technically, but is a rather non-standard way of importing. If the package Package1 you are importing does not have `BeginPackage`-`EndPackage` and `Begin`-`End` itself (which is a case sometimes), then you will create all its symbols in the public part of Package2 with such an import, and therefore, leak its details to the user. It is not a frequent case, but from the "black box" point of view importing into a ``Private` `` subsection adds extra protection.

Comment: It was not a suggestion, of course, just a clarification.  It's easy to misunderstand your comment and assume that it's the ``Begin["`Private`"]`` that makes the imported package private.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `Needs` lines to your kernel [`init.m` file](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html).

I would suggest changing the `init.m` file found in `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel`.

Comment: I have seen this <http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/automatically-load-packages-at-startup> but unable to get how it can be useful. I am able to get that .bak file in Mathematica kernel folder.