# Package autoloading not working in CDF and Player Pro

Tags: packages

I have made a package

```
 BeginPackage["top`"]
 t[x_]:=MessageDialog["This is top"]
 t1[x_]:=MessageDialog["This is top1"]
 EndPackage[]
```

and used the code of this link and I am able to auto load packages in `Mathematica` and it is working fine. But when I have used it with `Player Pro`. It is not working.

[Automatically load packages at startup](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/automatically-load-packages-at-startup)

```
 initFileName = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}];

(* Make a back-up *)
 CopyFile[initFileName, initFileName <> "_" <>
StringReplace[ToString@Round[DateList[]], " " -> ""] <> ".bak"];
exprs = Import[initFileName, {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}];

 Export[initFileName,
   Append[exprs, HoldComplete[Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]]],
     {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}
  ]  

  Row[{Button["Click for function t", top`t[5]], Button["Click for f1", top`t[7]]}]
```

I have deployed the notebook in to `CDF Player`. But when I am opening the `CDF` by closing Mathematica and opening it with `CDF Player`, it is not working. I have also added that package in Autoload folder of Mathematica Player. What should I do so that my CDF or Player Pro also works fine as `Mathematica` notebook was working fine by autoloading packages at startup?

I was getting this output in mathematica when I clicked at "click for function t".[image]

But I am not getting any output when I click on these two buttons in case of CDF or Player Pro.

Comment: what do you actually see? can you post a screen grab?

Comment: I don't know anything about Player Pro, but I doubt that the CDF Player is customizable like this.  CDFs are supposed to be portable and work everywhere, not only in a customized environment.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: i have edited my question.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21745/169)? I tried to summerize everything you'd need to load packages in Player Pro there, I don't think that things have considerably changed since then. The free CDF Player can not load packages, except if the CDF Player was specially signed, e.g. with an Enterprize License for Mathematica...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `init.m` file is different for Mathematica and Players:

```
expr = Dynamic[Column[{
      FileNameDrop[#, 3],
      Import[#, "Text"]
      }] &@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]];

CDFDeploy[ FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "userbasedirectory.cdf"}], expr, 
            Method -> "Standalone"]
SystemOpen @ %
```

[image]