# Call user defined function from many notebooks

Tags: function-construction

I wanted to ask a simple question. I am new to Mathematica, and I don`t find a way to call user defined functions just as I call Mathematica functions.

I want to use my own defined functions, but call them from different notebooks without including them in each notebook.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Add your function definitions to the [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file.

Comment: [(8221)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8221/121)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is the following. Evaluate in a Mathematica notebook the following

```
$UserBaseDirectory <> "/Kernel"
```

Go to the corresponding file and create through Mathematica (if it is not already existing) an init.m file with your definitions e.g.

```
whateverFunct[x_]:=3x+5;
```

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot (sorry for the duplicate, I hadn't found it)