# Autoloading MaTeX` and Rubi` via DeclarePackage[] in the user init.m does not work

Tags: packages, scoping, initialization, matex, autoload

> Former question: **Autoloading and adding code to a package in the user init.m**

I am using [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX), and I found the [`updateMaTeX[]`](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX#user-content-upgrading-or-uninstalling:%7E:text=The%20following%20function%20will%20automatically%20download%20the%20latest%20release%20of%20MaTeX%20and%20install%20it) function] at the GitHub repo.
I tried to add this to my `init.m` in the `` MaTeX` ``  context, and wrote

```
BeginPackage["MaTeX`"];
updateMaTeX[] :=
  Module[{json, download, target},
    Check[
      json = Import["https://api.github.com/repos/szhorvat/MaTeX/releases/latest", "JSON"];
      download = Lookup[First@Lookup[json, "assets"], "browser_download_url"];
      target = FileNameJoin[{CreateDirectory[], "MaTeX.paclet"}];
      If[$Notebooks,
        PrintTemporary@Labeled[ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace"], "Downloading...", Right],
        Print["Downloading..."]
      ]; URLSave[download, target],
      Return[$Failed]
    ]; If[FileExistsQ[target], PacletManager`PacletInstall[target], $Failed]
  ]; updateMaTeX::usage = "suggested at the MaTeX GitHub repo."
EndPackage[]; DeclarePackage["MaTeX`", {"MaTeX", "ConfigureMaTeX", "ClearMaTeXCache","updateMaTeX"}];
```

However this leads to two issues:

1. ([Solved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/5478)) The supposedly local variables ``` json``download``target ``` are touched in the `` MaTeX` ``  context, and picked up by the auto-completion. It's a simple fix to add `Remove[json, download, target]` to the code, but I wonder why no `$ModuleNumber` was appended to the symbols.
2. Autoloading does not work as expected. Type `MaTeX` in a new notebook and it is still undefined; evaluation causes this new symbol to be created in `` Global` `` . Typing `` MaTeX`MaTeX ``, it is undefined, but become defined as soon as it is evaluated; `` Global`MaTeX `` is simultaneously shadowed. At this point, the $\text{M}\!^\text{A}\!\text{T}\!_{\normalsize{\text{E}}}\!\text{X}$ document is accessible, but the symbol `MaTeX`(`` MaTeX`MaTeX ``) does not have any downvalues, and thus is not working.

Similar issues occur with the `` Rubi` ``  package. Therefore I wonder:

1. Is using `` BeginPackage["Package`"] `` outside the package `.m` a good practice?
2. Why `DeclarePackage` does not work as expected?

---

### Related Questions

1. [Automatically load packages at startup](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8221/72025)

Comment: Ad 1 - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/5478